# Scanner and JOptionPane not working properly together

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I have a `Scanner` and i am getting day of the week from console then i want to show day in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` method but its not working.

```
public class TestClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String day = scan.nextLine();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, day);
   }
}
```

what is wrong?

thanks in advance.

[image: my codes and output]

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error, it just scanning texts repeatedly from console and does not stop

Comment: Do you have a JFrame anywhere as the parent frame?

Comment: no, that's all my codes.

Comment: *i am not getting any error, it just scanning texts repeatedly from console and does not stop* -- How are you giving the input? Without a loop how is it scanning repeatedly?

Comment: Does each input show up in a dialog box?

Comment: @NicholasK that is my problem. you can test this little code. there is no loop but is giving repeatedly

Comment: @KevinAnderson no dialog box is apear, it just giving input from console again and again , non stoppable

Comment: I just ran your code, it worked without any issues. I got the output and there was no repeated scanning. Hope your code is in a `main()` Also after entering the day in the console, press **enter**

Comment: @NicholasK i entered whole class. i run this, type something in console its going next line and then still i can enter another text and so on.  never stop getting text

Comment: @NicholasK i added , you can check that. and please do not Down Vote.

Comment: the console accepts characters as long as your program is running. This is because the console is a windows process that runs independent of your program. That does however not imply that your program is reading all the console input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but I could find no issue with your code. Sharing what I've tried and maybe that'll help you debug your issue.

```
package simple.concepts.com;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter day");
        String day = scan.nextLine();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, day);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

While giving the input :

> Enter day :  Monday

(Press enter)

You should be seeing the pop-up with 'Monday'

EDIT:

Try running eclipse with administration rights. Restart and run again. Also run the program once and minimize all the windows, you should see it. It constantly takes input until and unless you close the pop-up.

Comment: I checked that and still scanning text repeatedly . what platform and java version do you using?

Comment: Windows 10. Java 1.8.

Comment: i also use exactly the same.

Comment: Try running eclipse with administration rights. Restart and run again. Also run the program once and minimize all the windows, you should see it. It constantly takes input until and unless you close the pop-up.

Comment: yes. now thats showing the dialog. but its still scanning text until i press ok button on Dialog. any way , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution you could create a JFrame and call the JOptionpane with the frame as it's parent component.

```
import javax.swing.*
// Other imp code
JFrame m = new JFrame();
JOptionpane.showMessageDialog(m,day);
```